# Doctrine2 (Symfony 2.8) connection to MS SQL Server 2016 Exp not working

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine

I try to connect to a MS SQl Server 2016 Express with Doctrine(2.4.8) in Symfony(2.8.17).

OS: Windows 10 - 64 bit
 - Webserver: IIS 10

When I execute the statment:

> php app/console doctrine:database:create

I get the following Message back:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\SQLSrvException]
>
> SQLSTATE [08001, 10061]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made becaus
>     e the target machine actively refused it.
>
> SQLSTATE [HYT00, 0]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
>
> SQLSTATE [08001, 10061]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has
>      occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance n
>     ame is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Boo
>     ks Online.

The SQL Server is on the same Maschine as the WebServer and the IDE.

I checked that it is possible to login on the DB with the DB-User I used in Doctrine. I also can create a connection when I manually build them in the ODBC Manager.

It's also possible to connect to the DB over Network.

Here are the connection parameters:

```
driver: sqlsrv
database_host: localhost\SQLEXPRESS
database_port: 1433
database_name: symfony
database_user: userdb
database_password: dbonepass
```

THX and greetings Sitox

Comment: `SQLSTATE [HYT00, 0]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired`. This here is probably due to a typo. Could we see the code snippet you se to connect to your SQL Server database?

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" the problem. I build a new developer maschine with Win 10 64bit, Apache 2.4 and php 7. On the new maschine there is no problem to execute the statment to create a new Database.

Greetings